# Time of delivery no later on

Tags: contract-law, international, sale-of-goods

I asked a friend to translate my sales contract to English. Here's the original:

"Thời gian giao hàng không trễ hơn: 30 ngày" which means the time of delivery should not be later than 30 days.

But here's my friend's translated version:

"Time of delivery no later on: 30 days"

Why did he use **no later on** rather than **later than**? Is it a mistake?

Comment: Why can't you ask your friend why he translated it that way?  But I would say that the use of "no later on" is not proper English which in a legal context could lead to ambiguity.

Comment: Try https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about the law,

Answer (score 1):

> Why did he use no later on rather than later than? Is it a mistake?

This is obviously a translation mistake. The phrase "no later on" is ambiguous because it doesn't have a clearly understood meaning, and is not proper English.